# replace all characters in string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to replace all characters in a string to "*" star character.

For example:

```
NAME_SURNAME : ANDREY KIMBELL
REPLACED     : ****** *******
```

How can I do this in Oracle PL/SQL ?

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure? (PL/SQL = stored procedure)

Comment: I want to use in a program block.

Comment: Use `TRANSLATE`. It will always be faster than regular expressions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use:

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7165/0)**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ANDREY KIMBELL', '\w', '*')
FROM dual
```

where `\w` is the Alphanumeric characters plus `_` equivalent of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Or if only letters:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ANDREY KIMBELL1', '[[:alpha:]]', '*')
FROM dual
```

Comment: woow. I have tried with  \w  parameter. Numerics and alphanumerics are replaced. Thank yo very much.

Answer (score 3):

you could to it like this

```
select regexp_replace('abdcde123fge','[A-Za-z]','*') 
from dual;
```

This replaces everything in the range of a-z and A-Z with a *

Comment: lad2025's answer is more smart and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TRANSLATE function:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(UPPER('Andrey Kimbell'),
                 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                 '**************************')
  FROM DUAL
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using regexp functions is to use the TRANSLATE function:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('ANDREY KIMBELL1', 
                 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                 '****************************************************')
FROM   dual;
```

(I deliberately didn't use the UPPER functionality before doing the TRANSLATE since that introduces a second function into the mix, and would slow things down)

ETA: as someone attempted to point out by editing my answer, rather than commenting on it, it turns out that translate is slower than using the regexp_replace - looks like the difference I was seeing was due to context switching in pl/sql. Or something.

Anyway, the below demonstrates what I now see:

```
set timing on

create table timing_regexp_replace
as
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(owner||' '||table_name||' '||column_name, '[[:alpha:]]', '*') col1
from dba_tab_columns;

create table timing_translate
as
SELECT TRANSLATE(owner||' '||table_name||' '||column_name, 
                 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                 '****************************************************') col1
from dba_tab_columns;
```

which returns:

```
Table created.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.96
Table created.
Elapsed: 00:00:02.87
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ANDREY KIMBELLasd123[]{}', '.', '*')
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question.